# How to tell why disabled voice control activating without obvious cause

Tags: keyboard, security, voice

Voice control is disabled in system settings, but I intermittently get a voice control popup appearing very briefly (I've not been able to get a screenshot but it's a little microphone icon).  Usually I guess it appears for a fraction of a second, at any rate too fast for me to tell what action it's doing.  When the popup goes away I also get a ping, which seems to indicate that an action has happened (though "audible " is turned off in system settings).  Sometimes the microphone popup goes away to be replaced by another one of similar size with three large horizontal (...) dots, before that closes too.  Once when it appeared I happened to have control held down, and then it stayed on the screen for seconds -- eventually being replaced by the three dots icon which also stayed there for seconds, then that disappeared too.

This happens even when I have my external headset plugged in and muted with the button on the headset, and the headset selected as input source.

It seems to be associated with keyboard activity, but I've not been able to identify why.  The keyboard activity seems different every time and I'm not usually using control/command/option when it happens.  It's not the option-F5 keyboard shortcut to enable voice control (that shortcut is disabled and has no apparent effect).

The popup looks similar to the image below but not identical.  Sometimes the popup has a triangular extension at the top that points to my cursor in a text editor.

How can I find out what is causing this?  For example:

- What can I try to identify / rule out causes?
- Could this be malware?
- Are there other possible explanations?

[image: Voice control icon looks similar to this]

Comment: Are you sure it's not Dictation? I don't have voice control, but that's the same icon as you get for Dictation. Double-press Fn [or globe] I think is the default trigger.

Comment: It was indeed dictation!  Took me a long time to find it.  The reason it got turned on in the first place was that enabling dictation has a default keyboard shortcut of hitting the control key twice quickly.  You get a popup asking whether you want to enable dictation, but if that arrives just as you're about to hit return, it just gets enabled.  So, as so often, the "private notice" and "consent" about this was meaningless, though for a different reason than usual.